# What is the meaning of けっこういらっしゃる in the following context?

Tags: meaning, translation

I came across the following sentence while watching the video [JLPT N3 LISTENING PRACTICE TEST 12/2023 WITH ANSWERS #5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw9E_MfN3AQ&t=1050s), at the timestamp 10:50:

> 食事がすんでいるのにずっと帰りにならない方がけっこういらっしゃるのが気になります

I heard the expression けっこういらっしゃる. I also typed it without kanji because I'm not sure of the spelling, and none of the words that are pronounced as けっこう sound right to me. After scratching my head, I finally gave up and used a translator, and this is what came out:

> I am concerned that some people do not leave after eating for a long time

I can understand what's before and whats's after けっこういらっしゃる, but I don't understand how that translates to "not leaving / staying".

Can someone please help me out? I thought いらっしゃる was like 行く.

Comment: "I thought いらっしゃる was like 行く." - have you heard/seen set phrases and idioms like  いらっしゃいませ ?

Comment: Yes, I have. That's why sometimes I have a hard time when they are used as regular verbs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

いらっしゃる here is a polite form of いる meaning "to exist" (see [いらっしゃる#3](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B/#je-4476)). As regards けっこう, it means "many/plenty in number" (see [結構#3](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%91%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%81%86/#je-22012)).

Therefore:

> 食事がすんでいるのにずっと帰りにならない方**がけっこういらっしゃる**

can be translated as

> ***there exist many people*** who do not leave after eating.